# applying shadow to scrollbar thumb

Tags: html, css

I have made this scrollbar:

[image]

As you can see, the thumb has box-shadow.
but the thing is, the shadow does not move with the thumb.
it works like this
[image]

> this is just some very rudimentary detial that i'm adding to get rid
> of this error so is giving me.
>
> this is on hell of a stupid error that does not go away

```css
.pr-20{
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.w-217 {
  width: 217px;
}

.h-220 {
  height: 220px;
}

.text-right{
  text-align: right;
}
.overflow-y-show {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  direction: ltr !important;
}

.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
}


/* the thin blue line */

.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 
  45%, #48eefc 45%, #48eefc 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 
  100%);
}

.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #48eefc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-y-show custom-scroll text-right pr-20 w-217 h-220">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your snippet suppose to reproduce the issue? Because it looks fine when I run it

Comment: @Novy well... that's the code i wrote and the images are how it looks like. so when u run it shadow is not glitchy?? can u give screenshots?

Comment: when i run it I got no shadow just a grey scrollbar. I did try it  chrome, safary, brave and firefox on mac os by the way

Comment: @Novy Edited the code

Answer (score 1):

Is That ok for you?

```css
.overflow-y-show {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  direction: ltr !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
}


/* the thin blue line */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 45%, #48eefc 45%, #48eefc 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #48eefc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
}
/* for firefox scrollbar has only two properties scrollbar-color scrollbar-width*/
html {
 scrollbar-color: #48eefc #8ea5b5;
 scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<div className="overflow-y-show custom-scroll text-right pr-20 w-217 h-217">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you have the same thing on different browser? which browser  are you using @Mr- A?

Comment: i'm using chrome, firefox ignores the styles and shows the default grey scrollbar

Comment: Ah ok ok if you look at spec for firefox for scrollbar has only two properties scrollbar-color scrollbar-width. you can check this  now.

Comment: some explanation could be useful, now one needs to reverse-engineer the logic by looking at code

Comment: I can understant . But I was thinking that looking at the code is why you are a software engineer @Vega4 so "RTFS"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem this way

```js
const scrollbar = document.querySelector('.custom-scroll');
        const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
        let updated = false;
        scrollbar.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            if (updated)
                return;

            updated = true;
            wrapper.classList.add('scale');
            scrollbar.classList.add('zoom');

            setTimeout(() => {
                wrapper.classList.remove('scale');
                scrollbar.classList.remove('zoom');
                updated = false;
            }, 1);
        })
```

```css
.wrapper {
            padding: 30px;
            width: fit-content;
            height: fit-content;
            background: #fff;
        }

        .pr-20 {
            padding-right: 20px;
        }

        .w-217 {
            width: 217px;
        }

        .h-220 {
            height: 220px;
        }

        .text-right {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .overflow-y-show {
            overflow-y: auto;
            direction: ltr !important;
        }

        .custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 9px;
        }


        /* the thin blue line */

        .custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 45%, #48eefc 45%, #48eefc 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
        }

        .custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #48eefc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #48eefc;
        }

        .scale {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }

        .zoom {
            transform: scale(0.91);
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="overflow-y-show custom-scroll text-right pr-20 w-217 h-220">
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```